# Upload image not saving

Tags: django

Views.py
I can not really figure out what the problem is .I have been trying many otherways but no avail .Please help to sort out this little problem

```
def user_account_dp(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        modelform = modelformimage(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=request.user.userdp)
       if user_profile_pic_fm.is_valid():
           user_profile_pic_fm.save()
           messages.success(request,'Successfully updated Profile')
           return redirect('gbiz1990:profile_account')
       else:
           messages.error(request,'chose a picture')
    else:
       user_profile_pic_fm =DpForm(instance=request.user.userdp) 
    return render(request,"gbiz1990/user_account/user_profile.html",{'user_profile_pic_fm':user_profile_pic_fm})
```

html.file

```
<form action='{{ action_url}}' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ user_profile_pic_fm.profilepic}} {% csrf_token %} <button type="submit">Save changes</button></form>
```

model.py

```
enter code here

class UserDp(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="userdp")
     profilepic =models.ImageField(upload_to="profile_image",null=True,blank=False)

def __str__(str):
    return self.profilepic
@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def create_user_userdp(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
   if created:
      UserDp.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Comment: can you show me model and modelform?

Comment: model.py added  please check it out

Comment: can you see folder name `profile_image` in project root directory?

Comment: Yes ,and another object model is using as well

Comment: did you get any error?

Comment: Nope all is work good .Apart from problem to upload an image file.

Comment: userDp.profilepic is empty? profile_image folder is empty?

Comment: Yes ,i can seem to be able to upload image .

Comment: uploaded image file stored in profile_image directory?

Comment: this is what i get  ,when ever i try to summit th form ,"no file selected "

Comment: ok, just for test: replace `{{ user_profile_pic_fm.profilepic}}` in html file with `<input type='file' name='profilepic' id='profilepic' />` and test it

Comment: Still does not work .I have extended two objects models as user profile models .The first extended user model is working perfectly fine .But this one seems not to work when ever a try to upload a file .Is there any limitation on the number of object models to be extended as User profile model ?